# Computing a recurrence table backward

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I am trying to understand how to compute a recursive equation backward say `n = 10` to `n = 1`. I am trying to solve a PDE for which the solution is only known in at some future time and that future value can be used to find a value at an earlier time. Can you please help me understand how I can get following series of multiples of 7 starting from 10th element which is 7. I tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
RecurrenceTable[a[n - 1] == 3 a[n], a[10] == 7, a, {n, 10, 1, -1}]
```

Comment: You could do a forward recurrence with `a[1]==x` and then solve for x at the end.

Comment: did you suggest RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 3 a[n], a[1] == x[1], a[10] == 7}, {a, x}, {n, 1, 10}]. I get a error    "RecurrenceTable::underdet: There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is underdetermined"

Comment: Try `aux = RecurrenceTable[{a[n - 1] == 3 a[n], a[1] == x}, a, {n, 1, 10}];
aux /. Solve[Last[aux] == 7, x]`.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I will use it solve FDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

b.gatessucks solution given in a comment should be recorded answer.

```
aux = RecurrenceTable[{a[n - 1] == 3 a[n], a[1] == x}, a, {n, 10}]
```

> ```
> {x, x/3, x/9, x/27, x/81, x/243, x/729, x/2187, x/6561, x/19683}
> ```

```
First[aux /. Solve[Last[aux] == 7, x]]
```

> ```
> {137781, 45927, 15309, 5103, 1701, 567, 189, 63, 21, 7}
> ```

But, of course, in this simple case there is

```
Reverse @ NestList[3 # &, 7, 9]
```